# debugging Laravel-4 artisan command

Tags: debugging, laravel-4

I have been using Laravel 4 since the start of the year. PHPStorm does not yet support Laravel 4 debugging. Are there any other alternatives?
I have some Artisan command code written in PHP. What is the best tool to debug the code (Single step, set breakpoint, examine values of variables etc)

Comment: What do you mean php storm doesn't support laravl debugging it has nothing to do with Laravel. Laravel is php and php storm can debug php, I have been using it on laravel 4 with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

I use Clockwork https://github.com/itsgoingd/clockwork

You can download the Chrome extension that works in conjunction with it here https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clockwork/dmggabnehkmmfmdffgajcflpdjlnoemp?hl=en